# Converting a pycaret pipeline to lightgbm.sklearn.LGBMClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, mlflow, shap, pycaret

I've defined and trained a lgbm model using pycaret.

When I fetch the model using
`model = mlflow.sklearn.load_model(model_name)`
the resulting model is of type pycaret.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.

This model type is not supported by shap.TreeExplainer, so I'd like to know if there is a way to convert the model into one of type lightgbm.sklearn.LGBMClassifier